# Change root ViewController programmatically

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to change root ViewController of my app programmatically. Once user registers I want different root ViewController. This is my code

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBarVC")

UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = vc
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.makeKeyAndVisible()

self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

After `vc` is presented I kill the app, and when I run it again the root ViewControler is the same. What am I doing wrong? I also tried the same code in AppDelegate, but no success.

Comment: Why not use a popover when a user isn't registered?

Comment: Because we don't want popover animation and this looked like the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set this in appDelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method according to current app settings , also you should use `window` not `keyWindow`

```
if(userExists)
{
   let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBarVC")

   UIApplication.shared.window.first?.rootViewController = vc

}
else
{
   let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginVC")

   UIApplication.shared.window.first?.rootViewController = vc
}
```

Don't use present as this will automatically change the root

Also another way to access windows (used when AppDelegate has a value)

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let homeController =  mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
appDelegate?.window?.rootViewController = homeController
```

Comment: In Swift 4 it should be `UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController`

Comment: The second way you added also won't work for the code above.

Comment: the second part is usually used when AppDelegate has a value i mean when you say in homeViewController and want to change root , but in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions  , AppDelegate still has no value